# Checkbox touch animation stucks

Tags: android, animation, checkbox, material-design

Please check the image attached:

[image: Screen Shot]

When I click on it, and do checked/unchecked, the touch animation stays there. And when i click on any other widgets on the screen or blank area, checkbox becomes normal.

Can anybody help me if you know the solution.

Comment: put anim file here

Comment: please add some code

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaI am not using any custom animation, It is default material design animation in 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your CheckBox is focusable. The animation you see is the focused state graphics. To get rid of that set focusable/focusableInTouchMode to 'false' or remove that state from CheckBox ripple.

Comment: Then that ripple effect will gone, that i don't want. Also it stops working, it becomes like disabled, and i am not able to interact with it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Actually I was using focusable/focusableInTouchMode for other controls in the screen but not directly on the checkbox but it was the issue. You save my life. Thank you :)